# Cant Access Value of spinner contol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have tried the following to access the value from the spinner control. The spinner is part of Microsoft Service Manager Wpf Controls dll but its just giving me the following about RouterdPropertyChangedEventArgs'1[System.Decimal]. My Question is how do I retrieve the value it self.

I attached the event as I would do in winforms to the following event handler

```
indexedOrderSpinControl.ValueChanged += SpinValueChanged;

private void SpinValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<decimal> e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("This should be the value of the spin control " + Convert.ToString(e.NewValue));
}
```

Sorry I should have explained I am trying to use the value in a linq query to retrieve the description of column as such

```
 private void SpinValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<decimal> e)
  {
    ObservableCollection<CustomColumnsModel> columnsList = this.WizardData.ConcreteCustomColumnsProxy;
   var q = columnsList.Where(a => a.ColumnIndex == (double)e.NewValue).FirstOrDefault())  ;
  }
```

Comment: Is your changed event being called and the value is incorrect, or is the method not called at all?

Comment: @davisoa Hi no its being fired but that is the value im getting in the messagebox instead of the control value

Comment: Have you simply tried casting the value to a `double` (or `decimal` if that's what it uses)?: `double value = (double)e.NewValue;`

Comment: When debugging, the `e.NewValue` what does contain? Does it work without trying to convert to string?

Comment: GUYS Please see above edit this is what i am wanting to really aceieve where  ColumnIndex is public int ColumnIndex { get; set; }